# How to auto-deploy to Compute Engine from Artifact Registry?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-build, google-container-registry, google-artifact-registry

**Context**

I'm working on an app. The code is in a Cloud Source Repository. I've set up a Build Trigger with Cloud Build so that when I push new commits, the app is automatically built: it's containerized and the image is pushed to the Artifact Registry.

I also have a Compute Engine VM instance with a Container-Optimized OS. It's set up to use my app's container image. So when I start the VM, it pulls the latest image from the Artifact Registry and runs the container.

**Issue**

So, currently, deploying involves two steps:

1. Pushing new commits, which updates the container in the Artifact Registry.
2. Restarting my VM, which pulls the new container from the Artifact Registry.

**Is there a way to combine these two steps?**

Build Triggers detect code changes to trigger builds. Is there similar way for automatically triggering deployments from the Artifact Registry to Compute Engine?

Thank you.

Comment: Add a build step that runs **gcloud compute instances update-container**  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/update-container

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks. This seems promising. But if I'm not mistaken, this command would start the new container image in the VM, but it wouldn't delete the old image from the VM. So, eventually, the VM would run out of disk space

Comment: That is a good question and I do not know the answer. Given how containers are actually a lot of small layers, and only the changed layers are downloaded, you would need to deploy maybe thousands of times depending on how much disk space you allocate to the Compute Engine VM instance. In development, I deploy maybe a dozen times per day for months and I never even thought about disk space issues - now I will.

Comment: You still need 2 steps: one to push the image, the other to deploy it on your VM. you can imagine a deamon script on your VM that scan periodically the image in Artifact registry and which update itself when a new version is detected, but your current architecture is better than that.